# What does "in occasione di" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I have difficulty understanding the meaning of the expression "in occasione di" in this sentence.

This text is about Big Ben.

> Tradizionalmente il nome viene riferito, per estensione, anche all'orologio e all'intera torre dell'orologio, alta 96,30m e costruita in stile neogotico. Il nome ufficiale di quest'ultima è pero diventato Elizabeth Tower a fine giugno 2012, ***in occasione del*** giubileo di diamante della regina Elisabetta.

Does the expression "in occasione di" in this sentence mean "due to" or "because of"?

Comment: I'd say:  to commemorate the Diamond Jubilee of Queen Elisabeth.

Comment: 'on the occasion of' is perfect there, while 'due to' absolutely doesn't render the correct meaning of 'in occasione di' in that context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it actually about English language.

Comment: I agree with DaG that the question as is phrased is off-topic; you should probably remove the translation part and ask for a comparison with e.g. "a causa di" or other terms equivalent to "due to" and "because of" that you already know of, in order to make the question on-topic and for you to have a useful answer at the same time. A translation coming with an answer, if any, will be a bonus.

Comment: I agree: you should reformulate the question; otherwise, it will be closed.

Comment: I edited my question and deleted the translation part.

Comment: I think in English the correct preposition is just **on**.

Comment: The problem is that you are asking for a translation into English, and not for the meaning of this expression or, as suggested by @kos, for a comparison with other expressions such as "a causa di".

Comment: Or, put in other words: the *topic* of the question must be strictly the Italian language. The question *may* involve a translation from English to Italian, but it *must not* involve a translation from Italian to English at any point.

Comment: In which sense did you “delete” the translation part, since you are start mentioning the difficulty you have in translating something, and the actual question is «Can I translate [such] as [such]»? I believe that ELU or ELL are much better places to ask such a question: just describe the meaning you need to convey, and they'll be glad to explain how to express it in English.

Comment: I think it's a pity that this question gets lost because it's interesting, so I have reformulated a little bit.

Comment: It means literally “on the occasion of”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Il nome ufficiale di quest'ultima è pero diventato Elizabeth Tower a fine giugno 2012, in occasione del giubileo di diamante della regina Elisabetta.

"Due to" and "because of" roughly mean "a causa di", and "a causa di" expresses a causality link;

"In occasione del" *itself* doesn't really *imply* a causality link, it implies that both events happened at the same time, although it also *strongly suggests* that two events were a good fit one for each other.

Take vacations as an example: you may well say that "In occasione delle vacanze sei andato a trovare dei parenti", but you'd probably never say that "A causa delle vacanze sei andato a trovare dei parenti".

So no, it doesn't mean exactly the same as "due to" or "because of".

---

If you're reasonably sure that the two events are causally linked, then you may well use "a causa di" in place of "in occasione del" (and hence also "because of" / "due to" e.g. in a translation), but *mind that this implies a loss in the meaning, since the temporality link between the two events is lost; in a translation you're better off using (as suggested in the comments by Elberich Schneider and egreg) the English equivalent "on the occasion of"*.

If you want to just convey that the two events happened at the same time, hardening the sense of causality disjunction, you can use another adverb altoghether (such as "durante" / "during").

So if you're reasonably sure that the two events are causally linked, then you may well use "a causa di" in place of "in occasione del" (and hence also "because of" / "due to" e.g. in a translation), but again, the temporality link between the two events is lost:

> The official name of the latter however became Elizabeth Tower at the end of june 2012, *because of* / *due to* Queen Elizabeth's diamond Jubilee.

If you don't want to lose the temporality link between the two events, in a translation you're better off using the English equivalent "on the occasion of":

> The official name of the latter however became Elizabeth Tower at the end of june 2012, *on the occasion of* Queen Elizabeth's diamond Jubilee.

If you want to just convey that the two events happened at the same time, hardening the sense of causality disjunction, you can use another adverb altoghether (such as "durante" / "during"):

> The official name of the latter however became Elizabeth Tower at the end of june 2012, *during* Queen Elizabeth's diamond Jubilee.